# Metodo java y test unitario

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio de clase,que este
El método predictedRenewalCostByDate recibe como parámetro una fecha
hasta la cual se quiere calcular el coste de renovación del dominio asumiendo que
nunca puede ser null (no es necesario aplicar validación sobre el parámetro). Para
el cálculo, hay que tener en cuenta que se calcula el coste desde la fecha en la que
se invoca el método hasta la fecha pasada por parámetros y teniendo en cuenta los
años que lleva el dominio registrado. Esto implica que no hay que incluir en el cálculo
aquellas renovaciones que son anteriores a la fecha actual.
Asimismo, hay que tener presente que un dominio se renueva de manera anual en
función de su fecha de expiración y tiene un coste de 9.99€. En caso de que la
fecha recibida como parámetro sea anterior a la fecha actual, se debe mostrar el
siguiente mensaje de error: “[ERROR] The date must be later than the
current date.”. Además, para poder calcular el coste de renovación, el dominio
debe tener activada la renovación automática, en caso contrario, el método debe
devolver 0.
Como la empresa de hosting quiere mantener a sus clientes más fieles en la
compañía, promueve una política de descuentos según la antigüedad de sus
clientes. La antigüedad de un dominio se calcula siempre a partir de su fecha de
registro. De esta manera, una vez se quiera renovar un dominio, si este se encuentra
en el primer año de antigüedad, no se aplica ningún descuento y, por lo tanto, el
precio de renovación será 9.99€; el segundo y el tercero año aplica un 5% de
descuento; el cuarto y el quinto, un 10%; y para clientes con una antigüedad superior
a 5 años, un 15%.
Por ejemplo, si un dominio fue registrado el día 14 de noviembre de 2022 con fecha
de expiración el 14 de noviembre del 2024 y se quiere predecir el coste de
renovación desde hoy (20 de marzo de 2024) hasta el día 10 de noviembre de 2027
(dato pasado por parámetro), los cálculos a realizar serían (teniendo en cuenta que
la fecha actual es antes de la fecha de renovación del 2024):
Registro del dominio 2022: no se incluye en el coste.
Renovación 2023: no se incluye en el coste.
Renovación 2024 (2 años de antigüedad → 5%): 9.49€
Renovación 2025 (3 años de antigüedad → 5%): 9.49€
Renovación 2026 (4 años de antigüedad → 10%): 8.99€
Renovación 2027: no se alcanza según la fecha.
Coste total: 9.49€ + 9.49€ + 8.99€ = 27.97€
Esta el la prueba unitaria que tengo que pasar:

```
public void testPredictedRenewalCostByDate() {
        WebDomain webDomain = new WebDomain("uoc.edu", "Gabriel Ferraté i Pascual", "gferrate@uoc.edu", "Hosting UOC",
                LocalDate.now().minusYears(30), LocalDate.now().plusMonths(6), 10000, true, true);

        assertEquals(0.0, webDomain.predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(6)));
        assertEquals(84.92, (double) Math.round(webDomain.predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate.now().plusYears(10)) * 100) / 100);

        webDomain.setRegistrationDate(LocalDate.now().minusYears(1).plusDays(1));
        webDomain.setExpirationDate(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1));
        assertEquals(28.97, (double) Math.round(webDomain.predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate.now().plusYears(3)) * 100) / 100);
        assertEquals(37.96, (double) Math.round(webDomain.predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate.now().plusYears(3).plusDays(2)) * 100) / 100);
        assertEquals(63.94, (double) Math.round(webDomain.predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate.now().plusYears(6).plusDays(1)) * 100) / 100);
    }
```

este es el metodo

```
public double predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate date) {
        if (date.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
            System.err.println("[ERROR] The date must be later than the current date.");
            return 0;
        }

        if (!autoRenew) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Calcular la antigüedad del dominio en años
        long yearsSinceRegistration = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(registrationDate, date);

        // Si el período de renovación es dentro del tiempo actual, el costo debe ser 0.0
        if (yearsSinceRegistration <= 0) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        // Calcular el número de renovaciones
        long numRenewals = yearsSinceRegistration;

        // Coste inicial
        double totalCost = 0;

        // Si la fecha final está dentro del año actual, se incluye la renovación actual
        if (date.isAfter(expirationDate)) {
            totalCost += renewalCost * (1 - calculateDiscount((int) yearsSinceRegistration));
            numRenewals++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < numRenewals; i++) {
            double discount = calculateDiscount((int) (yearsSinceRegistration - i));
            totalCost += renewalCost * (1 - discount);
        }

        return totalCost;
    }
```

caluclo de descuento

```
private double calculateDiscount(int yearsSinceRegistration) {
        if (yearsSinceRegistration <= 1) {
            return 0;
        } else if (yearsSinceRegistration <= 3) {
            return 0.05;
        } else if (yearsSinceRegistration <= 5) {
            return 0.10;
        } else {
            return 0.15;
        }
    }
```

Esta es la linea que me señala que falla cuando se hace el test
assertEquals(0.0, webDomain.predictedRenewalCostByDate(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(6)));

expected: <0.0> but was: <250.74900000000002>

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! bajo que condicion deberia ser 0 lo devuelto para una fecha posterior a 6 meses??? no nos hagas leer, todo, explicanos eso...

Comment: es un metodo de renovación de dominio y su coste, en la línea del test que me está parando el metodo indica que faltan 6 meses para la renovación y que el coste debe ser 0.0, pero me está saltando este número 250.74900000000002 en vez de 0.0, el teste falla en esa linea, ya que no se le está pasando bien, pero no encuentro el fallo...

Comment: no me contestaste.. tu metodo debe devolver 0 en una renovacion a 6 meses, porque???? cual es la regla que tengo que mirar para poder depurar tu metodo y entender porque tiene que dar 0?ç

Comment: debe devolver 0 por que no ha cumplido el año, el dominio se renueva anual, por lo que si es menor a un año, no debe renovar ya que le faltan 6 meses para renovar, por lo tanto debe dar cero ya que como no renuevas el coste es 0

Comment: Y eso que me comentas, lo calculas en que momento? esto es depuracion pura.. aprender a depurar es tan importante como aprender a programar. En que parte, esta esa regla??? en que parte de tu codigo??? fijate que ni es necesario mirar el resto, solo esa parte de tu codigo que deberia devolver ese 0....

Comment: Cambia los nombre de las cosas, por nombres que se entiendan.. long yearsSinceRegistration = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(registrationDate, date); que tiene registrationDate ahi????

Comment: calcula la diferencia de años

Comment: no pregunte eso.. que tiene la variable registrationDate?? la otra tiene la fecha actual mas 6 meses.. que valor da esa cuenta?? que valor resulta en yearsSinceRegistration ??? eso, debe dar 0 para que salga valiendo cero... depura.. segui tu codigo.. si no da cero, algo pasa... que pasa???

Comment: Buenas, Cloudent. He intentado reproducir tu problema, suponiendo que la fecha que pones primera, la de 30 años en el pasado, es el registrationDate; la otra fecha de 6 meses en el futuro la cojo como expirationDate y el 10000 como renewalCost y la cantidad que me sale no es la misma que tú indicas, es 251000.0. Supongo que estás haciendo algún redondeo interno que no se ve ahí. Pero no creo que tu algoritmo de cálculo se correcto en ningún caso.

Comment: Creo que uno de los problemas es el bucle for donde recorres todos los años pendientes de pago. Creo que deberías calcular el descuento total para un número de años, no para el año 1, el año 2, el año 3, ...